# VBA, How to find a value in a named range that is composed of two columns

Tags: vba, excel

I have a named range under a Excel sheet that is composed of two columns( 
the first one is for abbreviations the second one is for names)

what i'm asking for is to loop through this named range or use .find() to catch a value in the first column and get the opposite value on the seconde column.

any help?

Comment: There is an excellent example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839746.aspx).

Comment: Why do you want to use VBA? This seems to be a typical case for VLOOKUP or INDEX / MATCH (unless I misunderstood the question).

Comment: I need to extract data to use it on a macro

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to do so.

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim row As Range
Dim cell As Range

Set rng = Range("named range")

For Each row In rng.Rows
  For Each cell In row.Cells
    If cell = "RYO" Then
    MsgBox cell
    MsgBox cell.Next
    End If

  Next cell
Next row
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my answer

```
Sub findTwoColumns()
    Dim f As Range
    Dim firstAddress
    Dim myRng As Range
    Set myRng = Range("myRange")
    With myRng
        Set f = .Find("JNI", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        If Not f Is Nothing Then
            firstAddress = f.Address
            Do
                'msgbox f.Value   'here if you want o use the found value.
                'msgbox f.address 'here if you want o use the found address.
                MsgBox f.Offset(0, 1).Value 'take the value of the next cell
                Set f = .FindNext(f)
            Loop While Not f Is Nothing And f.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

You cand do something to take the value of the abbreviation (`JNI`) as a parameter.